# white space in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I want to know how to check if there is white space in a string or not in JSP.

EX :

String name = "Richard hailes";

I want to know if there is a space in above string or not.

Comment: Do you want to check it in JSP code or in Java code? The accepted answer indicates that you don't want to check it in JSP code at all, but in Java code. Writing Java code incorrectly in JSP files instead of Java classes really doesn't make it a "JSP problem". The answer of JB Nizet is the right one when it comes to real valid JSP code not for Java code which actually belongs in a Java class such as a servlet.

Comment: Also, note that there's a subtle but not unimportant difference between spaces (`0x20`) and whitespace in general (`\s`).

Comment: Thanks for the information BalusC. Your comments are informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `indexOf` function.

```
if(name.indexOf(' ') >= 0){
   // name have space
}
```

see [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very simple. So I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Since Java 1.5 (released 8 years ago) there's however another method which makes it more simple.

Answer (score 3):

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(name, ' ')}">
  It contains a space
</c:if>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info for info about the JSTL.

Answer (score 1):

public static boolean isBlank(String str) { int strLen; if (str == null || (strLen = str.length()) == 0) { return true;} for (int i = 0; i < strLen; i++) { if ((Character.isWhitespace(str.charAt(i)) == false)) {return false;}}return true;}
}

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression. See this sample;

```
    String patternStr = "\\s+";
    String inputStr = "Richard hailes";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if(matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println("Found");
     } else {
       System.out.println("Not Found");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this page](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/jsp/functiontaglist/fn-contains-tag.php) which describes how to use the contains function in JSP. You can use that to see if the string contains " ".